# Как сделать, чтобы кнопка выделялась полностью?

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Вот [это](http://jsfiddle.net/ferz/ZpsbC/embedded/result/) имеется.

Comment: ul a
{
    padding: 10px;
}
вот так!

Answer (score 1):

**Вот, держите** - http://jsfiddle.net/PqbZL/20/

*В чем проблема?*

Answer (score 1):

[Попробуй так](http://jsfiddle.net/XUqar/1/), должно все работать, к стати в коде Astorа глюк с выравниванием текста padding работает только как padding-bottom.

Comment: @Cone, глюк исправил, проблема была в том, что элементу <a> не задал display: block; // можно display: inline-block;

Comment: @Cone, да, и еще, совсем забыл - представленный Вами код не вполне кроссбраузерный, так как всеми нами любимый и уважаемый IE6 не поддерживает :hover для элементов, которые не являются ссылками.

...хотя IE6 уже на пенсии...

Comment: IE 6 уже в могиле, забудьте про него.

Answer (score 0):

<ul>
  <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">portfolia</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">contacts</a></li>
  <ul>

*{margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none;}
ul li {float:left;padding:5px 10px;background:#777;margin-left:10px;}
ul li:hover {float:left;padding:5px 10px;background:#333;}
ul li a{color:#eee;text-decoration:none;}